# Recommendations for clipping an entire scene in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm looking for ways to clip an entire unity scene to a set of 4 planes. This is for an AR game, where I want to be able to zoom into a terrain, yet still have it only take up a given amount of space on a table (i.e: not extend over the edges of the table).

Thus far I've got clipping working as I want for the terrain and a water effect:

[image: Look! My trees can float in mid air!]

The above shows a much larger terrain being clipped to the size of the table. The other scene objects aren't clipped, since they use unmodifed standard shaders.

Here's a pic showing the terrain clipping in the editor.
You can see the clipping planes around the visible part of the terrain, and that other objects (trees etc) are not clipped and appear off the edge of the table.
[image: Inside the Editor]

The way I've done it involves adding parameters to each shader to define the clipping planes. This means customizing every shader I want to clip, which was fine when I was considering just terrain.

While this works, I'm not sure it's a great approach for hundreds of scene objects. I would need to modify whatever shaders I'm using, and then I'd have to be setting additional shader parameters every update for every object.

Not being an expert in Unity, I'm wondering if there are other approaches that are not "per shader" based that I might investigate?

The end goal is to render a scene within the bounds of some plane.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to use Box Colliders as triggers on each side of your plane. You could then turn off Renderers on objects staying in the trigger with OnTriggerEnter/OnTriggerStay and turn them on with OnTriggerExit.

You can also use `Bounds.Contains`.

Comment: huh!! Great idea. Hadn't even thought of that.  They'd pop in/out of existence, but I guess I could also fade them based on the box volume overlap if I wanted.  That'd work great for the trees, but perhaps less well for something like a large base. Thanks! Still interested to know if there are other ways :)

Comment: Depending on your camera setup you could use camera clip planes or some form of occlusion culling. Other than that I cant think of another way not involving shaders.

Comment: Dave, is there any technique you know of that'd work well using a final camera buffer, rather than individual shaders on each item?  Maybe I actually need to try the individual approach and test the performance difference - other than the maintenance nightmare (having to customize shaders) it might work.

Comment: You may be able to do it with camera shader/camera effect but I am not good with shaders to tell you exactly how to do it, sorry.